# Open and display image in prettyphoto lightbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I’m trying to use the prettyPhoto lib. When someone clicks on an image on my view, the prettyphoto lightbox to open and display it in a nice manner.

I have added the prettyPhoto.css and prettyPhoto.js files from the github resource of Stephane Caron.

I added their references and did my bit of markup as well as jquery code.

---

---

```
<div class="item col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12 moments everyday others festivals isotope-item" style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px) scale3d(1, 1, 1); opacity: 1;">
            <a href="~/Resources/Images/ArtPreview/an eventful winter.jpg" class="vlightbox2" data-rel="" rel="prettyPhoto[Gallery1]">
                <img src="~/Resources/Images/ArtPreview/an eventful winter.jpg" alt="">
                <div class="caption">
                    <div class="info">
                        <h4></h4>
                        <div class="separator"></div>
                        <p></p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="vlb_zoom" style="position: absolute; display: none;"></div>
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="item col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12 moments everyday others nature isotope-item" style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px) scale3d(1, 1, 1); opacity: 1;">
            <a href="~/Resources/Images/ArtPreview/rebellion.png" class="vlightbox2" data-rel="" rel="prettyPhoto[Gallery1]">
                <img src="~/Resources/Images/ArtPreview/rebellion.png" alt="">
                <div class="caption">
                    <div class="info">
                        <h4></h4>
                        <div class="separator"></div>
                        <p></p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="vlb_zoom" style="position: absolute; display: none;"></div>
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="item col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12 moments others nature isotope-item" style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px) scale3d(1, 1, 1); opacity: 1;">
            <a href="~/Resources/Images/ArtPreview/Bulleh.jpg" class="vlightbox2" data-rel="" rel="prettyPhoto[Gallery1]">
                <img src="~/Resources/Images/ArtPreview/Bulleh.jpg" alt="">
                <div class="caption">
                    <div class="info">
                        <h4></h4>
                        <div class="separator"></div>
                        <p></p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="vlb_zoom" style="position: absolute; display: none;"></div>
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="item col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12 moments others travel everyday nature isotope-item" style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px) scale3d(1, 1, 1); opacity: 1;">
            <a href="~/Resources/Images/ArtPreview/with Love (2).jpg" class="vlightbox2" data-rel="" rel="prettyPhoto[Gallery1]">
                <img src="~/Resources/Images/ArtPreview/with Love (2).jpg" alt="">
                <div class="caption">
                    <div class="info">
                        <h4></h4>
                        <div class="separator"></div>
                        <p></p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="vlb_zoom" style="position: absolute; display: none;"></div>
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="item col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12 moments everyday animal others isotope-item" style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px) scale3d(1, 1, 1); opacity: 1;">
            <a href="~/Resources/Images/ArtPreview/Hannibal 4.jpg" class="vlightbox2" data-rel="" rel="prettyPhoto[Gallery1]">
                <img src="~/Resources/Images/ArtPreview/Hannibal 4.jpg" alt="">
                <div class="caption">
                    <div class="info">
                        <h4></h4>
                        <div class="separator"></div>
                        <p></p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="vlb_zoom" style="position: absolute; display: none;"></div>
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="item col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12 moments travel nature everyday isotope-item" style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px) scale3d(1, 1, 1); opacity: 1;">
            <a href="~/Resources/Images/ArtPreview/smplArt (2).jpg" class="vlightbox2" data-rel="" rel="prettyPhoto[Gallery1]">
                <img src="~/Resources/Images/ArtPreview/smplArt (2).jpg" alt="">
                <div class="caption">
                    <div class="info">
                        <h4></h4>
                        <div class="separator"></div>
                        <p></p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="vlb_zoom" style="position: absolute; display: none;"></div>
            </a>
        </div>


$(document).ready(function () {
    $("a[rel^='prettyPhoto[Gallery1]']").prettyPhoto({
    allow_resize: false, 
    allow_expand: false,
    show_title: true,
    animation_speed: 'normal',
    slideshow: 7000,
    theme: 'pp_default',
    modal: false
});

});
```

If I click the photos, instead of opening up the prettyphoto lightbox the images open up in the next tab.

Comment: Press F12 you should see console being opened look for any errors in it

Comment: hi @Novice
okay. It says: prettyPhoto() is not a function. In this line --> $("a[rel^='prettyPhoto[Gallery1]']").prettyPhoto({

Comment: @VinoDivinoOsteriano tis error would suggest that your library is not loading, hence the `prettyPhoto()` cannot be found. You did not include a complete example. Please review your example and edit if needed.

Comment: @VinoDivinoOsteriano as Twisty rightly suggested your prettyphoto.js isn't getting loaded you should check your paths but for a quick test or if you  still couldn't get it to work you can try a CDN https://cdnjs.com/libraries/prettyPhoto

Comment: hi. it works now. two things I changed. Firstly put that jquery code block inside a 'document.ready'. And - I explicitly added the ref to the jquery file, even though I had it added in the bundleConfig since this is a MVC project I was working on. It's weird it should have drawn the ref. from the bundle itself but as it appears I had to 'hardlink' the jquery file explicitly for this to work.